# How do I adjust a vector by an amount from another vector

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I'm being very dense, but I can't work this out.

If I have a direction vector, say `(0,1,3)` and another vector, maybe `(0.1,0.2,-0.3)` which is like the amount I want to adjust the first vector. But the adjustment should be done relative to the direction of the original vector.

So, if the first vector is point "left" and the other vector is pointing "a little bit 'up' and to the 'left'", the result vector would start from the first one but then, in the direction it's facing, point a little to the left and up?

So the "left and up" would be opposite for two direction vectors, one pointing positive, the other negative.

Comment: @mvw Sort of. Keep it's general direction. I think the correct term is that the second vector is on the tangent plane to the first vector.

Comment: Let the original vector be $x$ and the adjustment vector $a$, then you have a part of $a$ pointing in $x$ direction: $a_x = (x \cdot a) x / \lVert x \rVert^2$ and a part $a_{x^\top}$ orthogonal to it which add up: $a = a_x + a_{x^\top}$.

Comment: Okay, is that `(x.a)x` second part a cross or dot product of `x.a` and `x`?

Comment: So like $a_x = \frac{(x . a) . x}{||x||^2}$?

Comment: Yep. The norm $\lVert x \rVert^2 = x\cdot  x$ is to get a unit vector $e_x = \frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert}$ in $x$-direction.

Comment: So, I'm not very good at math; but if I drop that into wolfram http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%7Br%2Cg%2Cb%7D+%3D+%28%28%7B3%2C2%2C1%7D.%7Br%2Cg%2Cb%7D.%7B3%2C2%2C1%7D%29%2F%28%7C%7C%7B3%2C2%2C1%7D%7C%7C%5E2%29%29+%2B+%7Bu%2Cv%2Cw%7D I don't understand how I can do the dot product between a scalar and a vector...

Comment: Nah, you just take $x \cdot a = \sum_{i=1}^3 x_i a_i$ and divide the number by $\lVert x \rVert^2 = \sum_{i=1}^3 x_i^2$. With this number you multiply each component of the vector $x$. This gives $a_x$ the part of $a$ in direction of $x$.

Comment: So... $\vec{a_{x\top}} = \vec{x} \cdot (\frac{\vec{x}\cdot\vec{a}}{||\vec{x}||^2})$

Comment: No, without the $\top$ that I used to name the orthogonal part. And you could write it alternatively as  $a_x = \left(\frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert}\right) \left(a \cdot \left(\frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert}\right)\right) = e_x \left( e_x \cdot a\right)$.

Comment: Oh right, and with $a_x$ I can just vector add it to $x$ to get the adjusted vector direction?

Comment: Yes, you would only use the part of the adjustment $a$ which is in $x$ direction, so the result is still in $x$ direction. I am not sure if that is the best way to use your adjustment but it is one possibility. Another way would be to calculate the magnitude of the adjustment $a$, and to modify the magnitude of $x$ with it. $x' = (\lVert x \rVert + \lVert a \rVert) \frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert}$.